# jQuery form validation not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html

Can someone tell me why this form validation works in Firefox and not in Internet Explorer?
I need to make it work on ALL browsers.

Currently. the form is being submitted on explorer without validation.

Thanks for your assistance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Simple Form Validation</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#form2").validate({
        rules: {
          name: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true}
          email: {// compound rule
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        url: {
          url: true
        },
        comment: {
          required: true
        }
        },
        messages: {
          comment: "Please enter a comment.",
          name: "upgrade",
          email: "valid email only"
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  </head>


  <body>
    <form id="form2" method="post" action=""><br />
      Name * <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />
      E-Mail *<input type="text" name="email" /> <br />

      URL <input type="text" name="url" /> <br />
      Your comment * <textarea name="comment" ></textarea> <br />
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"> 
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens in IE? You get any error? Form is being submitted even though data is empty?

Comment: you have 'insert here' set as an email as a tip, which isn't an email. maybe try email@domain.com

Comment: ...and, bottom line, trying to have it work in "ALL" browsers is an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I think your syntax was a bit off.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#form2").validate({
        rules: {
          name: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true}
          email: {// compound rule
              required: true,
              email: true
          },
          url: {
             url: true
          },
          comment: {
             required: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          comment: "Please enter a comment.",
          name: "upgrade",
          email: "insert here"
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it still does not validate :( Did you try it yourself?

Comment: No, perhaps you could provide your `html` as well.

Comment: It looks like it does work in IE, it just doesn't show the messages. In IE9 which I tested it in you have to activate the ActiveX controls on the page for the messages to show up...not ideal

Comment: I've decided to use Javascript validation instead. It now works.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your jQuery Validation Plugin (jquery.validate.js) needs to be updated.  I was using version 1.7 and had the same issues you were experiencing.  Validation worked fine in Chrome, but did nothing (i.e. no validation errors appeared) in IE7 and IE8.

Try upgrading to the latest version of the plugin to see if it helps.

As of this moment, the most recent version can be downloaded from:
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery-validation-1.11.1.zip

Reference:
http://blog.degree.no/2012/01/jquery-validation-not-working-in-ie7-and-ie8/